# wxPython TxtCtrl box background not updating?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I am running into a problem with a simple program that changes the color of the background when it receives a command from a different machine through TCP. The background only updates when I run my mouse over the window. I am running this through the local network so it should be near instant response. I am using wxPython for the frame. I don't think I have overly complicated code. Relevant code:

```
    threader=threading.Thread(target=self.threading)
    threader.start()
def threading(self):
    host="192.168.1.122"
    port=4100
    s=socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(1)
    c,addr=s.accept()
    print "Connected"
    while 1:
        data=c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        data=data.split("_")
        reading=int(data[1])
        pin=int(data[0])
        if pin == 1:
            if reading<20:
                self.front_left.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        elif pin == 2:
            if reading<20:
                self.front_right.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        elif pin == 3:
            if reading<20:
                self.bottom_left.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        elif pin == 4:
            if reading<20:
                self.bottom_right.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        else:
            pass
    c.close()
```

I need this code to be instant as this will be going on a robot that will tell if objects are too close(which is why there is red background when it gets within 20 cm of object). Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better not call wx functions other threads. Keep all your UI in the main thread and communicate with it somehow. I use events for similar purposes, so I would probably define my own event,

```
(MyOwnEvent, EVT_MY_OWN) = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
```

Handle it in the main thread,

```
self.Bind(lib.BarCode.EVT_MY_OWN, self.OnMyOwn)
```

and call from the thread handling the TCP

```
wx.PostEvent(main_window, MyOwnEvent())
```

Or if you want to simplify your work, just use wx.CallAfter to set the color, and then possibly refresh.

Comment: To be precise, the [wxPython wiki[(http://wiki.wxpython.org/MainLoopAsThread) state explicitly that the GUI may only be called from the main thread. Otherwise thread-safe ways have to be used. In the specific case ``wx.CallAfter`` would be the simplest and best approach.